# making Color-relief from a rasterfile

Tags: gdal, gdaldem

I have a tempreture raster file, its min value is `-125` and it's max is `50` I want to make a color-relief file of this raster,
I tried to use `gdaldem` to make it. It works but the problem is with its bounds, I used a color file text as bellow

```
-126 0 0 50
-83 10 10 100
-41 30 30 150
10 70 70 200
18.5 100 100 225
19 170 170 255
20 57 151 107
20.5 117 194 103
21 230 230 128
21.5 202 157 75
22 185 154 100
25 220 220 220
27 250 200 255
30 100 100 200
```

Well I think `gdaldem` first tries to make the image histogram equlizer and then make a color-relief, this is why my raster become as following

[image]

but it must be as

[image]

I tried to add `-125` as `nodata` but nothing changed, what other options do I have to make a color-relief file from this raster?